# Java Check if enum value is part of a returned set of other enum values

Tags: java, enums

I got an enum with 3 values using Java. I got classes which are related to 1 or more of the enum values.

I know how to create a list and make an iteration, but is there a better way to return a single value of related enum values in which I could check if containing another value? For example something like:

```
public MyEnum mySupportedValues() 
{
    return MyEnum.Value1 | MyEnum.Value3; //not even sure if thats correct
}
```

And then be able to check if an enum value is a part of the supported list:

```
public boolean isMyEnumSupported(ClassA aInstance)
{
    MyEnum aSupportedValues = aInstance.mySupportedValues();
    MyEnum mySupportedValue = getMyValue();
    return aSupportedValues contains mySupportedValue; //not sure how to check
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `EnumSet`?

Comment: @EJP Yes it is. Since you were the first to comment it, if you add an answer with an example, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Hint: I started writing my answer before EJP commented ;-) ... so consider at least handing out some upvotes, as most of  the answers are correct in their way ;-) x2

Comment: @GhostCat upvoted. If EJP won't write an answer until tomorrow, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 3):

Lightweight solution

```
public class Main {

    private enum Flag {
        VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4;

        int getBitFlag() {
            return 1 << ordinal();
        }

        boolean isSupported(int bitFlag) {
            return (0 != (getBitFlag() & bitFlag));
        }
    }

    private static int mySupportedValues() {
        return Flag.VALUE1.getBitFlag() | Flag.VALUE3.getBitFlag();
    }

    private static boolean isMyEnumSupported(Flag flag) {
        int supportedValues = mySupportedValues();
        return flag.isSupported(supportedValues);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flag toBeTested = Flag.VALUE3;
        System.out.println(isMyEnumSupported(toBeTested) ? "Supported" : "Not Supported");

        toBeTested = Flag.VALUE2;
        System.out.println(isMyEnumSupported(toBeTested) ? "Supported" : "Not Supported");
    }

}
```

EnumSet is based on collection framework and uses iterator when you check `contains`. Above solution uses bit-masks.

**Note**: Solution will work correctly only up to 32 values.

Comment: Maybe "light weight" in cost of "performance" (which kinda absolutely does not matter on such a level); but not at light weight in terms of implementation cost. The whole idea of the Enum class is to get **away** from using plain ints and doing bit arithmetic.

Comment: I agreed with you GhostCat. Another thing I must mention here is, this solution will work only up to 32 values. Although, could you please elaborate on, why it is implementation wise expensive to add two method to enum?

Comment: It doesn't add real value. Java has means to exactly express this functionality; thus you are adding code (aka *complexity*) to that class, without *any* need to do so. In other words: this code will surprise most java programmers, because the "standard" solution is to work with EnumSet. And surprising other programmers always carries a certain "smell".

Answer (score 2):

Enums in Java are not just simple numerical values that you can "numerically" or together.

Your method thus must return some kind of "collection" of enum values, so it should read

```
public EnumSet<MyEnum> mySupportedValues() {
  return EnumSet.of(MyEnum.Value1, MyEnum.Value2);
}
```

instead. As "some collection" in this context pretty much boils down to [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) being the correct choice here.

And then your other method can simply use the `contains()` method of that EnumSet object you got from that other method.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with slight modifications of your code.

```
public EnumSet<MyEnum> mySupportedValues() 
{
   return EnumSet.of(MyEnum.Value1, MyEnum.Value3);
}


public boolean isMyEnumSupported(ClassA aInstance)
{
   EnumSet<MyEnum> aSupportedValues = aInstance.mySupportedValues();
   MyEnum mySupportedValue = getMyValue();
   return aSupportedValues.contains(mySupportedValue);
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html
`EnumSet`is a specialized `Set` class to take up `enum` constants.